# How To Store Hmong Characters In MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, internationalization, character-encoding

I've read a number of articles on storing multi-language strings in MySQL, but I can't seem to find anything specific (or credible) on Hmong.  I have no trouble with latin (European) languages, but if someone could enlighten me on Hmong, that would be terrific.

Thanks!

P.S.  Using PHP for the scripting, if anyone cares.

Comment: I didn't realize I was being ambiguous until bobince pointed out that RPA might be considered by the answerers.  Sorry about that.  I can safely store the romanized (latin) alphabet.

Also, I am now enlightened that Hmong Pahawh isn't in Unicode so that's the new hurdle.  

1 - Is there a font/character set used by a majority of those typing in Hmong?

2 - Is there a way to store these strings to be output back to the screen at a later date?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

What alphabet are you using?

If you're talking RPA, you'll have no trouble with that as it's just Latin. If you're talking about Pahawh, I'm afraid there's not much you can do. Not only is it not (yet) specified in Unicode, but there doesn't seem to be any standardised character set for it at all, only ad hoc encodings generally using the Unicode Private Use Area.

Do you have existing text in this alphabet? Who are your potential users and what keyboards and fonts do they use?

If you're interested in helping get Pahawh into Unicode, see the [Pahawh-hmong](http://evertype.com/mailman/listinfo/pahawh-hmong_evertype.com) list for discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Since Hmong isn't part of unicode i'm afraid you are quite stuck unless you want to manually add and compile a new charset into mysql.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-character-set.html